# How can I do without memory leak getInstance()

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm using the static instance object for data related from another activity in my application. But this leads to a memory leak.

```
public class ChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       private static ChartActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);

        instance = this;

        bla bla bla
   }
    public static ChartActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

I need to call the floating action button in another activity. I don't hide it or I need to update the recyclerview in another fragment again

```
ChartActivity.getInstance().fabadd.hide();
```

```
ChartActivity.getInstance().fabadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // 
    }
});
```

```
ChartActivity.getInstance().recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

How can I solve this without memory leak? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of this can you explain your requirement why you need to use this static instance?

Comment: You can initialize an instance in a static block

Comment: Storing data as static object is **highly discouraged** in android development, even in java development as well. I would recommend passing data by intent over activities.

Comment: For example, I need to change the textview in this activity. So I am changing the textview in it from another activity. Is there another way? @Md.Esaduzzaman

Comment: The question has been more clearly updated. @Md.Asaduzzaman Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

look for how to pass data using intents, it simple and you don't need to use static instances of your activity.

Example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putString("keyData",name); //this keyData will be the key to get the information from activity one to second activity.
startActivity(i);
```

in your second activity you should check

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if(i.hasExtra("keyData"))
{
    textview.setText(i.getExtra("keyData"));
}
```

**Edit**

**First activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key",true);
startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if(i.hasExtra("key") && i.getBooleanExtra("key",false)==true)
{
    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //all buttons or other views that you need to change visibility you can do it from here
}
```

that's basically it.

Comment: I don't use it to pass data. For example I need to trigger button/floating action button in other fragment or activity

Comment: why not just pass a variable to your activity/fragment and if it's present just do the logic of the fab/button that you need to run

Comment: Because fab in another fragment. I have to do this.

Comment: or I have to hide. ChartActivity.getInstance().floatingactionbutton.hide();

Comment: Thank you @DemoDemo but I have to do this problem instantly. with singleton structure.. but I don't know which one is correct